# Eclipse: Dynamic Web Project

Tags: eclipse, web, dynamic, project

How do i create a "Dynamic Web Project" in eclipse?

I am trying to learn primefaces. I am trying to follow video [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XU8QQ9UNQLE&list=PLmzsN85WJPD5qjqhgix08fZOnkvSaNCaZ)
Here I am supposed to go to file->new and then create a dynamic web project.
I do not have this option however.

I have tried to look for "install new software" and search for it there, however i have not found it.
What am i doing wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You require the `Eclipse Java EE Developer Tools`. Install them using the instructions at https://wiki.eclipse.org/WTP_FAQ#How_do_I_install_WTP.3F .